# Problem with legends, leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am not very good at js and new with leaflet so i my code may be a bit messy but stil...
I have a problem with my legends, i have 2 legends and many overlays and i want some legends to be "linked" with some overlays. 
I followed every example i saw but still i have a problem with the name of the layer, it's like my names don't work so controls can't change legends properly

I made a jsfiddle that can explains more obviously my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/qs6wkru4/3/

I want the legend to change when i click on "Cuivre" and not on others...

Comment: the external ressources in your jsfiddle point to "localhost". can you please update the jsfiddle so that it's working

Comment: Oh didn't see ! Done

Comment: so your actual version is now http://jsfiddle.net/qs6wkru4/4 ...the link above not up to date anymore ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Leaflet-Version is 1.0dev.
There the eventlayer.name is missing.

I also added a counter so see when the other legend has to be removed.
Was this the functionality you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/7LskL5e1/

Comment: It's working ! So it comes from the version of leaflet?

U did what i wanted, having a legend that changes with layers. I think i will go with "base layers" instead of layers because i only want 1 layer at time !

Comment: yes.with baselayers you will have to listen to the baselayerchange-event... something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/3xnxfo6q/4/