# Need to Add/Remove .png Legend with Leaflet Layers Control?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, legend, layer-control

**Supporting Links**

Website Location: 
http://bit.ly/2fXCiTH 
.JS File Location: 
http://bit.ly/2g56W0U

**Trying to accomplish**

I would like to have a specific .png legend associated to each individual layer.

**Problems so far**

I have not been able to get code to recognize the layers being fired

**My non-working code so far**

---

```
var temperaturesLegend = L.control({
    position: 'bottomright'
});
var xwLegend = L.control({
    position: 'bottomright'
});

temperaturesLegend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML +=
        '';
    return div;
};

//temperaturesLegend.addTo(map);

xwLegend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML +=
        '';
    return div;
};

// count plus 1
others = 1;

// Add and remove layers
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer) {
    // Switch to the temperaturesLegend...
    if (eventLayer.name === 'temperatures') {
        // xwlegend.removeFrom(map);
        temperaturesLegend.addTo(map);
    } else { // Or switch to the xwlegend...
        if (others < 1) {
            xwLegend.addTo(map);
        }
        others++; // temperaturesLegend removeFrom(map);
        //xwlegend.addTo(map);
    }
});

// Add and remove layers
map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer) {
    temperatures = eventLayer;
    //console.log(eventLayer.name);
    // Switch to the xwlegend...
    if (eventLayer.name === 'temperatures') {
        this.removeControl(temperaturesLegend);

    } else { // Or switch to the xwlegend...
        others--;
        if (others < 1) {
            this.removeControl(xwLegend);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Rather than making people step through your complicated code, I'd suggest creating a much simpler example which can run stand-alone on https://jsfiddle.net/. Create a basic example with 2 layers, and associated PNG legends, and we can help you figure out how to switch the legend when the layer changes. The principle can then be expanded to fit within your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stephen, As you said, this is a very complicated .js file ( the section above ) is only a small piece. If you take a look at the site, there are approximately (8) Base maps & (30) main layers, probably double the combined possibilities. I thought someone may have run into this problem as well and have a code solution that might be customized into a fix.

Comment: (Cont.) Initially the site loads a weather temp. layer *(comprised of a basemap, a JSON data layer and a heat-map tile layer) and we have a .png legend for temperatures, there is a layer for windspeed/direction..etc.. that we have legend(s) for each individual layer, and so on and so on.

Comment: (Cont..) Most associated weather data providers (ie) NOAA, OWM, Aeris, etc... do not provide the ability to include a specific legend with a specific weather layer. BUT Leaflet does offer the ability for a map overlay (map.on/.remove) overlay control. I have read here on stack several people attempting the same with similar code as I provided above. http://bit.ly/2zcyyG6

Comment: Please don't use bitly links - there's no need to obscure or track the URLs, and it just makes things harder for people trying to answer your question. Can you clarify which parts of the answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68941/how-to-add-remove-legend-with-leaflet-layers-control aren't working? Where on the map at https://www.xtremeweather.org/ should the legend be displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to obscure the links, they are just so long... 

the problem i ran into with the code above is two fold. The way I was testing was to basically have the first legend "temperaturesLegend" show under the default map/layer and the have the "xwLegend" show up if you selected any other layer.  (1) I could not get the temperaturesLegend to come back after selecting another layer and (2) the xwLegend would not replace itself, it would continue to add. So if you went to one layer then another you would have two instances of the legend side by side.

Comment: *(Cont.) - The Legend was to show up in the bottom right hand side.

Comment: As it stands I believe this question is still far too complicated for Stack Exchange - it currently requires people to *debug your application* rather than *test a function*. I definitely suggest that you simplify this to something that people can run and test themselves. The basic principle is "how can I change the legend when the layer changes?", which doesn't require your entire application to test

Comment: Link for .JS File Location https://www.xtremeweather.org/static/js/tracker.js gives 404.